# use cmd.exe to change directory and run command in that directory

Tags: cmd

All I want to do is:

1. change to specific directory of a different drive
2. run a command in that directory e.g. dir

I need to do this in one line using cmd.exe starting from a different drive

I would do this like this:

```
c:
cd temp
dir
```

so in one statement so far I have:

```
cmd /c c: & cd\temp & dir
```

But this just gives me dir for the P: directory which I start from. How can I get dir returned from c:\temp?

I can't run a batch file and it must be in a one-line statement.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You may want to invoke CD with the /d option, thus not only changing the current directory on drive c: but also going there (in case you are not already on that drive).

```
 cmd /c "cd /d c:\temp && dir"
```

Answer (score 6):

you use && or & to separate multiple commands

if the cmd window is already opened and running from command line

```
 c: && cd\temp && dir
```

or

```
cmd /c && c: && cd\temp && dir
```

Comment: & and && both allow multiple commands, but for && runs the seconds only if first is successful

Comment: Are you simply running this from a command line or are you spawning the cmd.exe process from some other app?  Because both & and && worked for me

Comment: I'm testing on the command line but going to run it in c# app. Note that I also need to change to a different drive as well e.g starting drive is P: and the cmd line needs to change to C:

Comment: if you are already at the command prompt get rid of the "cmd /c "

Comment: it's got to work in c# app too so I'm using that to run the cmd /c

Answer (score 3):

You want quotes around that command line:

`cmd /c "cd c:/ & dir"`

Comment: that still returns dir from the P drive

Comment: This answer adds something useful. You need the quotes around your command, else each action will be executed independently. As Stagg says, you might want to add the /d option to change drives, though

Comment: The quotes tip here is what solved my issue